# How to scrape headings in about page?

Tags: python-3.x, scrapy

I'm trying to scrape the headings in about page but I tried so much and failed due to not the proper understanding of what to do? I'm a beginner. So I require help.

```
import scrapy
from ..items import DmoztutorialItem


class DmozSpiderSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'Dmoz'
    start_urls = [
        'http://dmoz-odp.org/',
        ]

    def parse(self, response):
        items = DmoztutorialItem()
        Navbar = response.css('#main-nav a::text').extract()
        Category_names = response.css('.top-cat a::text').extract()
        Subcategories = response.css('.sub-cat a::text').extract()

        items['Navbar'] = Navbar
        items['Category_names'] = Category_names
        items['Subcategories'] = Subcategories

        yield items

        # Nav_page = response.css('#main-nav a::attr(href)').extract()
        Nav_page = 'http://dmoz-odp.org/docs/en/about.html'.extract()
        # About_heading = response.css('h1+ p , #mainContent 
                # h1::text').extract()

        items['Nav_page'] = Nav_page
        # items['About_heading'] = About_heading
        yield response.follow(Nav_page)
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you tell what kind of output do you need? It is very unclear from your post.
Check this example, where you can:

1. Get some data;
2. Call request to another page with date saved;
3. Yield final data.

Hope it will help you.

```
import scrapy


class DmozSpiderSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'Dmoz'
    start_urls = ['http://dmoz-odp.org/']
    nav_page = 'http://dmoz-odp.org/docs/en/about.html'

    def parse(self, response):
        # collect data on first page
        items = {
            'Navbar': response.css('#main-nav a::text').extract(),
            'Category_names': response.css('.top-cat a::text').extract(),
            'Subcategories': response.css('.sub-cat a::text').extract(),
            'Nav_page': self.nav_page,
        }
        # save and call request to another page
        yield response.follow(self.nav_page, self.parse_nav, meta={'items': items})

    def parse_nav(self, response):
        # do you stuff on second page
        items = response.meta['items']
        items['something'] = 'something'  # add your logics
        yield items
```

Or make separate logins for separate pages:

```
import scrapy


class DmozSpiderSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'Dmoz'

    def start_requests(self):
        reqs = (
            ('http://dmoz-odp.org/', self.parse_main),
            ('http://dmoz-odp.org/docs/en/about.html', self.parse_nav),
        )
        for link, callback in reqs:
            yield scrapy.Request(link, callback)

    def parse_main(self, response):
        items = {
            'Navbar': response.css('#main-nav a::text').extract(),
            'Category_names': response.css('.top-cat a::text').extract(),
            'Subcategories': response.css('.sub-cat a::text').extract(),
        }
        yield items

    def parse_nav(self, response):
        items = {
            'something': 'something',   # add your logics
        }
        yield items
```

Comment: I want to move to another page i.e about and grab data from that page. The thing I tried was to grab first heading of about page but failed.

Answer (score 0):

To parse a different HTML page, you need to yield a [`Request`](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/request-response.html#request-objects) object with the target URL as the first argument for its constructor, and do the parsing in the method of your spider that you pass to the constructor of that `Request` object as the `callback` parameter.

I strongly encourage you to complete the [Scrapy tutorial](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/intro/tutorial.html). What you are trying to achieve is covered in the [Following links](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/intro/tutorial.html#following-links) section.

Comment: It worked. But the next problem appeared. I added another URL of a page and another item in first function parse also. Then I made another function for another page by the name def parse_editor(self, response): items = response.meta['items'] items['Heading'] = response.css('#mainContent h1::text').extract() yield items But its not scraping the second page data.

Comment: Please, complete the Scrapy tutorial first as suggested, and ask your new question on a separate Stackoverflow question.